# Number of non isomorphic group such that order of each element contained in $\{1,2,3,4\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I want to find all the groups $G$ whose $\pi_e \subseteq \{1,2,3,4\}$, where $\pi_e = \{ o(x) : x \in G \}$. Is it possible such type of classification of a group. I would be thankful for any kind of help.

Comment: What is an element of order $0$? Do you want to find all of the groups (as you say in the body of your question) or do you just want the **number** of groups (as you say in the header)? Do you want all groups of arbitrary cardinality, or just finite groups?

Comment: Identity element of $G$ whose order is $0$. I want to find all group.

Comment: This thing skip in my mind , extremly sorry, I will correct it. Thanks for remind me of my mistake.

Comment: Even the finitely generated case is going to be too hard. Look up the bounded Burnside problem.

Comment: It is widely believed that "almost all" finite groups have exponent $4$, so this problem is untractable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A strictly easier problem is the case of having all the orders being in $\{1,2,4\}$, which is the same as saying you want $g^4=1$ for all $g\in G$.

For finitely generated groups, we know the [Burnside group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside_problem) $B(n,4)$ is finite (Sanov 1940).  This is a group with $n$ generators with the only relation that $g^4=1$ for all $g\in B(n,4)$.  Every finitely generated group with your property is a quotient of some $B(n,4)$.  So, if you manage to find all the normal subgroups of $B(n,4)$ for each $n$, you have at least enumerated all the finitely generated such groups.  You cannot avoid $B(n,4)$ because it is the universal such group for each $n$.  Even $B(2,4)$ is rather large with $2^{12}$ elements (Tobin 1954).

I could imagine the infinitely generated case to be arbitrarily complicated, and I don't know anything about it.

Allowing elements of order three, all I can say is they do not commute with nontrivial elements of order dividing four, since their product would be of order six or twelve.

Comment: If the order of $g$ is 3, then $g^4\ne1$, which makes things even worse.

Comment: Also, I think that it's not known whether all quotients of $B(k, 12)$ with orders of elements $\leq 4$ are finite.

Comment: @Ivan Thanks, I fixed that large error.